# ruby execution; os x

Tags: ruby, structure, execution

I know this is a little lazy; but I really don't feel like learning ruby (know too many other languages already) & I'm sure someone experienced could explain this in less than a minute; I purchased a big red button (http://www.dreamcheeky.com/big-red-button) for a bit of showmanship.  I want it to run a bash script when the button is pressed; there are a few libraries out there on git hub; and this one looks really promising:

https://github.com/derrick/dream_cheeky

Except I really don't understand the folder layout that it downloads in; From my limited experience I know you have to install gems and then run code based off of that; I don't know how to run this thing though - any advice would be welcome; I'm running os x & do have ruby installed (2.1.1p76).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to understand the gem (dream_cheeky) structure, just do this:

1) Run `gem install dream_cheeky`. This will install the gem, you will not see it in the current directory and you don't need to.

2) Create run_dream_cheeky.rb and put the example Ruby code from the readme there. The first few require lines from the readme will make sure dream_cheeky is loaded.

```
# this line ensures gems will be available to your Ruby script
require 'rubygems'

# this will make dream_cheeky gem available in your currect Ruby script
require 'dream_cheeky'
```

3) Run the script with `ruby run_dream_cheeky.rb`